# I need a example for strcat_s()

Tags: c++

Can you please give me an example for c++. which works on Visual studio 2019.

I tried this

```
  char test_name[50];
    char SQLQueryViewMARKS_12A[] = "SELECT *FROM Marks_12A WHERE Test_Name = ";
    cin>>test_name;
    strcat_s(SQLQueryViewMARKS_12A,sizeof(SQLQueryViewMARKS_12A),"'/0 ");
    strcat_s(SQLQueryViewMARKS_12A,sizeof(SQLQueryViewMARKS_12A),test_name);
    strcat_s(SQLQueryViewMARKS_12A,sizeof(SQLQueryViewMARKS_12A), "'/0");
```

The expected result was :

If user entered UT

The query must get concatenate to

```
char SQLQueryViewMARKS_12A[] = "SELECT *FROM Marks_12A WHERE Test_Name = ' UT ' ";
```

Comment: @ejendra Saradhi There is no space in the array SQLQueryViewMARKS_12A to accommodate the appended string.:)

Comment: "I tried this" - okay? Did it not work? If you want an example of the usage of this function, [here you go](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code/question is ***very*** vague - the more information you give us, the more we are likely to be able to help you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost right. The only thing that is missing is the space for the additional string that you would like concatenated to the original:

```
char SQLQueryViewMARKS_12A[128] = "SELECT *FROM Marks_12A WHERE Test_Name = ";
//                         ^^^
// Give your string more space to ensure that additional characters have place to fit
//
strcat_s(SQLQueryViewMARKS_12A,sizeof(SQLQueryViewMARKS_12A),"'/0 ");
```

Note that although `strcat_s` works fine in C++, `std::string` from the Standard C++ library gives you a much more powerful alternative:

```
std::string SQLQueryViewMARKS_12A = "SELECT *FROM Marks_12A WHERE Test_Name = ";
SQLQueryViewMARKS_12A += "'/0 ";
```

Comment: As a `std::string` do you really need to explicitly add the null character to the end? and what's with the space following it?  Am I just being dense?

Comment: @Baldrickk Its not `\0`, it's `/0`. It comes straight from OP's code, along with the space at the end.

Comment: Me being dense then (I know it's in their code, but I misread it as a null)   This isn't helped by "/0" not being in their expected output...  I was reading it as their manually null terminating the strings to be concatenated.